# How to detect Flash runtime errors?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm developing an AS3 application with the commandline tools from the Flex SDK. My workflow is:

1. write code
2. compile with `mxmlc`
3. run the SWF file in favorite webbrowser
4. repeat

The second step catches compile-time errors, but what about run-time errors and warnings? And `trace()` output? How can I see that?

I'm not using any IDE with debugging capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the debug version of the Flash player and Firebug for Firefox, then you can see the traces and errors in the console.

When a run-time error occurs that isn't caught by an exception handler you will get a popup telling you about the error.

Why not get http://www.flashdevelop.org/? It's free and it has debugging, profiling and all other goodies you can expect from an IDE.

Comment: I did use FlashDevelop before, but I got tired of rebooting to Windows. There's no Linux version :(

Answer (score 1):

Although the Flash debugger is a pretty good choice. I would personally suggest [Monster Debugger](http://www.monsterdebugger.com/). It is a great debugger with a very intuitive user interface and it has a plethora of features that make debugging extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

Flash player debugger writes the output of `trace()` to the flashlog.txt file. Its location is hardcoded and is different on different systems. On Linux it is in ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt. In order to have The debugger to actually write into that file, you need yet another file, mm.cfg, it's location and name are again hardcoded. It should be in ~/mm.cfg. It may contain many different options, but the one you are interested in is `ErrorReportingEnable=1`.

You may then `$ tail -f ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/flashlog.txt` to see the progress as the file is been written to.

Note that the directory and the file must be writable by the user running the player. Flash player will not issue any warnings if that is not the case, and will fail silently.

Also note that if you are happened to be on Linux, then there isn't a 64-bit version of a debugger player... However, the player runs fairly well under Wine, the Windows version that is.

You may debug using commandline debugger found in SDK. it's called fdb (fdb.exe or in Apache Flex fdb.bat on Windows). It has similar to gdb interface, can do breakpoints, some runtime code evaluation, disassemble functions, look up stack frames and their variables and most of the other stuff you'd expect a debugger to do. I'm usually running it from Emacs, but I would imagine that running it from Vi[m] or whatever editor you are using shouldn't be a problem...

If you were using Emacs, it is actually possible to hook up Flymake to a part of the SDK that does syntax checking while you type. You can find more info on how to do that here: http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=9238 (thanks Philippe).